# MySQL update all products for created_at and updated_at in descending time

Tags: mysql

I have a table of 1000 products and I want to update the column "created_at" and "updated_at" for all the products but in this schema of time

batch 1 => product with id 1000, 999, 998, 997 get "created_at" and "updated_at" change to NOW() - 1 days

batch 2 => product with id 996, 995, 994, 993 get "created_at" and "updated_at" change to NOW() - 2 days

batch 3 => product with id 992, 991, 990, 989 get "created_at" and "updated_at" change to NOW() - 3 days

And so on, and if this is possible, is it possible to randomize the number of chunks like instead of every 4 products, it will be like each (2 or 3 or 4) products.

All i have now is : `UPDATE products SET products.created_at = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -1 DAY;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? MySQL 8+ have ROW_NUMBER() and other tools that may help you.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 8.0 answer...

```
WITH
  randomised AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) + 3) DIV 4 * 4   AS offset
  FROM
    example
)
UPDATE
  example
INNER JOIN
  randomised
    ON randomised.id = example.id
SET
  example.created_at = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL randomised.offset DAY)
```

- `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND())` assigns every row a random position
- `(x + 3) DIV 4` changes that from `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...` to `1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3...`
- Multiply that sequence by 4 again to get `4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,12...`

Then join back and update.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00d2f397b25206fabc1b1e17da021bbc

Comment: First of all thanks a lot, it works, but it does not retain the order like i wrote, i mean  here is how it looks : [link](https://i.imgur.com/n3KOpHz.jpg)

Comment: When i said "to randomize the number of chunks li instead of every 4 products, it will be like each (2 or 3 or 4) products" i forgot to say to keep the same order so each 2 or 3 or 4 products means ex : id 900, 899 have NOW()-4 days then 898, 897, 896 have Now()-8 days and so on

Comment: @user3012958 - So, you just want the group size randomised for each group?  Do you need the prevalence of each group size to be equal, or normally distributed, etc?  Please edit your question and write out all the characteristics and assumptions you rely on, even if they seem really basic and obvious to you.  For now, here are some examples of alternative ways to calculate the offset : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e4fbc55c45c3aeedfc9716025d68848

Comment: the third one is very close to what i need but here's is what output that i expect to have : [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8fd39ff4ced6210d0396ad7b32513f68)

From the newer id to the oldest, and the time part does not matter only the date that is important to be something like : 02/22, 02/22, 02/22, 02/21, 02/21, 02/20, 02/20, 02/20, 02/20, etc

Comment: @user3012958 Please update your question. You stated -4 days then -8 days, etc, which disagrees with your example.  You also didn't answer about normal distribution vs equal prevelance, etc.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cb889cdc305df05e2d97e737db4ea71

Comment: excuse me i forgot to update my question, i did now.

Comment: so yes i wanted it normally distributed, and your last example is exactly what i needed, so thank you a lot.

Comment: Using mySql 8 it works fine but executing the same sql give an error under mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.34-MariaDB.

``You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE products INNER JOIN
  randomised ON randomised.id = products.id
SET
...' at line 8``

Can you give me a hint on how to fix it  ?

Comment: MariaDB is not MySQL, it's a fork that happened before MySQL8, which means that the syntax does not always match. Please open a new question specifically about your new query's error.

Comment: here is the new question, if by any chance you can help, thanks in advance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426252/sql-executed-under-mysql-v8-works-fine-but-not-under-version-mariadb-v15

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do with a ( select union ) with join, then you can just keep adding entries as needed vs changing a query each time.  Just to see the output, try the following query by itself, then you can see the context of the update query

```
select 1000 productid, 4 daysChanged
union select 999, 4
union select 998, 4
union select 997, 4
union select 996, 8
union select 995, 8
union select 994, 8
union select 993, 8
union select 992, 12
union select 991, 12
union select 990, 12
union select 989, 12
```

Then apply an update

```
UPDATE products 
      INNER JOIN 
      ( entire query from select above ) ThingsToUpdate
         on products.id = ThingsToUpdate.productid
   SET created_at = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -ThingsToUpdate.DaysChanged DAY,
       updated_at = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -ThingsToUpdate.DaysChanged DAY
```

But I dont know why you would want to change BOTH columns and not just the one for updated.  If a product was created on a given time, why change it, but its your data.